# Forward Prometheus exporter metrics to another Prometheus located in a different Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

Here's my scenario:

I have multiple K8S clusters, a central one and multiple edge clusters.

In the central cluster I have a full monitoring solution based on Prometheus.
For the edge clusters there are multiple Prometheus exporters that I want to scrape, but I can't have the metrics stored locally (in a local Prometheus deployment). What I need is to collect the metrics and forward them to the central cluster's Prometheus.

The main concerns for storing them locally are required disk space and the disk IO footprint. So a local Prometheus instance (stateless), that only forwards the collected metrics to the central cluster would work.

The question is, is this something I could achieve? And how.

Comment: Check https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/federation/ and https://thanos.io/

Comment: Thanks! Federation doesn't help (AFAIK) as I need to forward to the central cluster, so push not pull. Thanos / Cortex are indeed some options, just that these are not yet part of my software stack and if there's something available based on plain Prometheus (plus some lightweight proxies) I would go for it. Just that I don't know any.